# How to remove line containing a specific string from file?

Tags: string, bash, sed

I have a file BookDB.txt which stores information in the following manner :

```
C++ for dummies:Jared:10.67:4:5
Java for dummies:David:10.45:3:6 
PHP for dummies:Sarah:10.47:2:7
```

Assuming that during runtime, the scipt asks the user for the title he wants to delete. This is then stored in the TITLE variable. How do I then delete the line containing the string in question? I've tried the following command but to no avail :

```
sed '/$TITLE/' BookDB.txt >> /dev/null
```

Comment: Are you look for `grep -v "$TITLE" BookDB.txt`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can for example do:

```
$ title="C++ for dummies"
$ sed -i "/$title/d" a
$ cat a
**Java for dummies**:David:10.45:3:6
**PHP for dummies**:Sarah:10.47:2:7
```

Note few things:

- Double quotes in sed are needed to have you variable expanded. Otherwise, it will look for the fixed string "$title".
- With `-i` you make in-place replacement, so that your file gets updated once sed has performed.
- `d` is the way to indicate `sed` that you want to delete such matching line.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. The -i was what I was missing.

Comment: @JaredAaronLoo not only `-i`, you need to add double quotes otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @AvinashRaj That seems to be the case for OS X at least, on Ubuntu it actually doesn't work if you use `-i ""`, not very handy if you're making shell scripts that should work on multiple OS's...

Answer (score 4):

Your command should be,

```
sed "/$TITLE/d" file
```

To save the changes, you need to add `-i` inline edit parameter.

```
sed -i "/$TITLE/d" file
```

For variable expansion in sed, you need to put the code inside double quotes.